# Update all documents in a collection in Mongodb with a new field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell, mongodb-update

I have a collection named employees with documents like.

```
{
first_name:"john",
last_name:"doe"
}
```

I want to run an update query which adds a new field like `{name:'john doe'}`

I know it can be done like this

```
db.employees.find({}).forEach(doc=>db.employees.update({"_id":doc._id},{$set:{name:doc.first_name+"-"+doc.last_name}}))
```

but its taking a lot of time when i am using mongo compass with db running in atlas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it by using an [`update` aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

```js
db.employees.update({
  "first_name": {"$exists": true},
  "last_name": {"$exists": true},
  "name": {"$exists": false}
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "name": {
        "$concat": ["$first_name", " ", "$last_name"]
      }
    }
  }
],
{"multi": true}
)
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EKIM6IlLRQe).

Answer (score 0):

Use the
db.collection.updateMany()
to update all documents that match a specified filter.

for example:
To update all documents in the sample_airbnb.listingsAndReviews collection to update where security_deposit is less than 100:

```
    use sample_airbnb

db.listingsAndReviews.updateMany(
  { security_deposit: { $lt: 100 } },
  {
    $set: { security_deposit: 100, minimum_nights: 1 }
  }
)
```

The update operation uses the
$set
operator to update the value of the security_deposit field to 100 and the value of the minimum_nights field to 1.

this was taken from :https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/crud/update/

Comment: That's for adding a field with fixed values. In my case the value of the field is calculated by joining `first_name` and `last_name` . It should be something like $set:{name:"$first_name"+" "+"$last_name"}

Answer (score 0):

`db.collection.updateMany(filter, update, options)`
=> [updateMany](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#mongodb-method-db.collection.updateMany)

```
db.employees.updateMany({
  "first_name": {"$exists": true},
  "last_name": {"$exists": true},
  "name": {"$exists": false}
},  
{
  "$set": {
    "name": { "$concat": ["$first_name", "-", "$last_name"] }
  }
}, 
{ upsert: true}
)
```

! Don't forget `use db_name` first, to select your db.